# How to install monodevelop-database on Ubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop

I installed the latest version (V5.10) of MonoDevelop on Ubuntu V14.04.3. After installation I tried to install monodevelop-database, but the installation fails

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-database
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 monodevelop-database : Depends: libmono-npgsql4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libmono-system-data2.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: monodevelop (< 5.7.0.660.) but 5.10.0.871-0xamarin2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried already install -f and update/upgrade commands, but that does not solve the issue. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Jordy

Comment: If you look at this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/kCUtrwP.png) I took from Synaptic, you'll see that the most recent version of monodevelop-database is only 5.7.